# Is there a faster way to change my sound inputs and outputs?

Tags: macos, audio, speakers, input-source

I use multiple sound inputs and outputs. For example, for outputs I have my internal speakers, Air Parrot, and Bluetooth speakers. For inputs I have my internal microphone, Line In, Air Parrot, and a Bluetooth microphone.

To switch between these I go to Sound Preferences and select either the Output button or Input button and then select the device I want to use and then close the Sound Preferences.

Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.** You can select any connected device via the Volume icon in your menu bar.

To do this, hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down first before clicking on the volume icon. This will give you a choice of both Output Devices and Input Devices and you can just use your mouse to select the device you want. You can also use this as a quicker way to open your Sound Preferences directly.

**NOTE:** If you do not have the volume icon in your menu bar, you can enable this in your Sound Preferences.